# Laravel return UploadedFile object instead of image path

Tags: php, laravel

In my `update` method in the controller when i try to `dump` the requested data
all attributes comes fine but the `image` printed as `object` not the `imagePath` that is saved in the database

[image]

Update method

```
    public function update(Request $request, SlideShow $slideshow)
    {
        $slideshow->update($request->validate([
            'title_en' => 'required',
            'title_ar' => 'required',
            'link' => 'nullable|url',
            'image' => 'image'
        ]));

        dd($slideshow);
        $slideshow->uploadImage();

        session()->flash('success', __('dashboard.slideshow.edit_success'));
        return redirect()->route('admin.slideshow.index');
    }
```

`SlideShow` model

```
class SlideShow extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['title_en', 'title_ar', 'link', 'image'];

    public function uploadImage($imageName = 'image')
    {
        if(request()->has($imageName)){

            \Storage::delete($this->image);

            $uploadedImage = request()->$imageName->store('slideshow/');

            \Image::make('storage/'.$uploadedImage)->resize(870, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save();

            $this->update(['image' => $uploadedImage]);
        }
    }

    public static function search($request)
    {
        return  static::where(lang('title'), 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `SlideShow` model look like? Are there any accessors/mutators that are affecting your `image` property?

Comment: @whitwhoa i update my question and add the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior. When the request is made, Laravel converts the files in the request to the UploadedFile class. Since you're accessing the validated data from the request, this is what is returned. You're directly filling these values as attributes, and the UploadedFile doesn't automatically convert to a path, so this should probably not be included in the first update.

Anyway, in your code you're actually including in your question has the `dd()` method before you call the `uploadImage` method, and this method saves the path and does not try to safe the entire UploadedFile class. So if you dump it after it probably has the correct value there, can you verify this?

I'd do it like this:

```
  public function update(Request $request, SlideShow $slideshow)
    {
        // validate first
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title_en' => 'required',
            'title_ar' => 'required',
            'link' => 'nullable|url',
            'image' => 'image'
        ]);

        // only pull the data that we can update right now
        $slideshow->update($request->only(['title_en', 'title_ar','link']));

        // handle and store image if needed
        $slideshow->uploadImage();

        session()->flash('success', __('dashboard.slideshow.edit_success'));
        return redirect()->route('admin.slideshow.index');
    }
```

and then the method on the model:

```
    public function uploadImage($imageName = 'image')
    {
        if(request()->has($imageName)){

            \Storage::delete($this->image);

            $uploadedImage = request()->$imageName->store('slideshow/');

            \Image::make('storage/'.$uploadedImage)->resize(870, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save();

            $this->update(['image' => $uploadedImage->path()]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i dump it after upload image it dump the object also

Comment: but it fixes when i use the `path` method it return to me the path that i will save in database

Comment: Yeah missed the method in the model. But I'd remove the `image` from the first method, if for some reason something goes wrong when the uploadImage method is called, you end up with dirty data in the database. Does it actually save by the way? Does the update return true when you try to store the model with the full UploadedFile in there?

Comment: yah it returns with the `temp` path

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered if the solution works for you? Thanks